# GridSearch fit method error : TypeError [Tuning the parameters for RNN model]

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, grid-search

CONTEXT : " Building a Next-word Predictor using RNN "

I have made a LSTM model around which I want to tune number of epochs and batch_size. However I can't get past fit method of GridSearch.

Please click on the links to watch the code:

X_train is a 50 words list from a book, while y_train is 1 word list that comes after 50 words.

[CODE FOR THE MODEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcWxf.png)

[CODE FOR GRID SEARCH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbnuQ.png)

[ERROR WHILE EXECUTING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6vH3.png)

THANKS FOR THE HELP

Answer (score 1):

I think you are forgetting to put your keras model into a sk-learn wrapper without wrapper it is not possible to run grid or random search on keras models. Like pass your model in keras Classifier function build_fn.

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

    model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=Model, epochs=10, batch_size
=20, verbose=1)
Random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=model, cv=KFold(3), param_distributions=params, 
                          verbose=20,  n_iter=10, n_jobs=1)

Random_result = Random.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

If you want to see more Please go to the link. Here Working random search model is performed.

[Random Search Link Kaggle Kernal](https://www.kaggle.com/sohaibanwaar1203/hyperparameter-tunning-and-cnn-visualization?scriptVersionId=11619218)